# discord.py rewrite - how to implement sharding

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I know that the bots joined to more than 2500 servers have to implement shards, and I want to know how sharding works and see the examples.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [AutoShardedBot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=autosharded#discord.ext.commands.AutoShardedBot) which is built in and not too different from a normal bot instance. I highly suggest you read the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) before you try to tackle this yourself though.